# Replacement of deprecated function cardinality(c) in Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, jmodelica

In the [documentation](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/ModelicaReference.Operators.%27cardinality()%27.html) it is indicated, that `cardinality()` function is deprecated and should no longer be used. However, it is still used in the libraries such as ThermoSysPro.

e.g.

```
if (cardinality(C) == 0) then
 some code
end if;
```

where `C` is `FluidInlet` or `FluidOutlet`

Could anyone give a simple example of how it could be replaced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual solution is to make the connector conditional, and if enabled you require that it is connected.

For physical connectors you can see how heatports and support is handled in:
`Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.ConditionalHeatPort`
`Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Interfaces.PartialElementaryOneFlangeAndSupport2`

For control signals you can see how `p_in`, `h_in` etc are handled in 
`Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT`
`Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_ph`

However, the connectors of ThermoSysPro belong in neither of those categories and that should ideally also be cleaned up.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I know, that could be used in this regard, is the `connectorSizing` annotation. It is described in the [MLS](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf) chapter 18.7.

It is used a number of times in the Modelica Standard Library, e.g. in `Modelica.Blocks.Math.MinMax` via the parameter `nu`. When using it, the tool automatically sets the modifier for `nu` according to the number of connections to it.

```
  parameter Integer nu(min=0) = 0 "Number of input connections"
    annotation (Dialog(connectorSizing=true));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealVectorInput u[nu];
```

In the example below, `nu=2` is generated by Dymola automatically when creating a connection in the graphical layer. I have removed the graphical annotations, to make the code more readable.

```
model ExCS
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.MinMax minMax(nu=2);
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine sine(freqHz=6.28);
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k=0.5);

equation 
  connect(sine.y, minMax.u[1]);
  connect(const.y, minMax.u[2]);
end ExCS;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `cardinality()` operator is used in `Modelica.Fluid.Sources.BaseClasses.PartialSource`, and in a similar way in other fluid libraries (`IBSPA`, `AixLib`, `Buildings`, `BuildingSystems` and `IDEAS`), in the form

```
  // Only one connection allowed to a port to avoid unwanted ideal mixing
  for i in 1:nPorts loop
    assert(cardinality(ports[i]) <= 1,"
      each ports[i] of boundary shall at most be connected to one component.
      If two or more connections are present, ideal mixing takes
      place with these connections, which is usually not the intention
      of the modeller. Increase nPorts to add an additional port.
     ");
   end for;
```

I occasionally had models from users who somehow ended up with more than one connection to a `ports[i]`. How this happened was not clear, but I find the use of `cardinality()` useful to catch such situations, which otherwise can yield to mixing in the fluid port which the user did not intent and which are hard to detect.

Comment: I also think that this function is rather useful, but it is depreciated and it will be removed in the future for my understanding. There must be some genuine reasoning behind if the developers decided to remove it. Though it would be interesting to hear it.

Comment: ..and on the back of that question: what will you be using for that purpose in the future, when cardinality has been removed? It's strange to have a feature deprecated, but no clear successor/alternative named.